# Sequelize Why password field validation is alway running even if I am not updating password

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am working with Nodejs, sequelize and mysql. I have below user model with username and password required fields. I have declared some validation rules.

During my email validation function when I try to update verified field to true password field validation performs and function failed with below error.

Please anyone can guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            isEmail: { args: true, msg: 'email format is not correct' },
            notNull: { args: true, msg: 'email can\'t be empty' },
            notEmpty: { args: true, msg: 'email can\'t be empty string' },
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: { args: true, msg: 'password can\'t be empty' },           
            len: { args: [5, 50], msg: 'password length must be more than 5 characters' },
        }
    },
    verified: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    token: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    expiresIn: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
```

User model fields are being updated here.

```
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id } });

if (!user) res.redirect('/signup');

if (user.expiresIn.getTime() > Date.now()) {
    console.log('time check');
    if (user.token === token) {
        console.log('verified');

        user.token = null; 
        user.verified=true, 
        user.expiresIn=null;
        await user.save();
        res.redirect('/login');
        
    } else { 

        console.log('token failed');
        res.redirect('/signup'); 
    }
    
    
} else {

    console.log('token expired');        
    await user.update({token: null, expiresIn:null});
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

```
(node:3328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: password length must be more than 5 characters
    at InstanceValidator._validate (/home/amir/tuts/web/myApp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50:13)
    at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (/home/amir/tuts/web/myApp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:60:7)
    at async InstanceValidator.validate (/home/amir/tuts/web/myApp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:54:12)
    at async model.save (/home/amir/tuts/web/myApp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2377:11)
    at async module.exports.email_verification (/home/amir/tuts/web/myApp/controllers/authController.js:152:13)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason why password validation was running.

Password field in my user model I should use min validation instead of len

Revised password field validation.

```
password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: { args: true, msg: 'password can\'t be empty' },           
            min: { args: 5, msg: 'password length must be more than 5 characters' },
        }
    },
```